# Holo.Light theme but with white overflow dots?

Tags: android

If you set your app's theme to Holo.Light then you can get light popup menus, dark text, etc, which is what I want. However, my action bar is using a custom darker color and I want the overflow menu (dots) to go back to being white (as they are when you use Theme.Holo). What do I need to override in my theme to make that happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowStyle</item>
</style

<style name="OverflowStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/custom_asset</item>
</style>
```

Or use the dark action bar theme

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

Comment: Good response thanks. However what if the action bar is split (android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow") in this case the button is either in the action bar at the top and uses the dark theme, or at the bottom using the white theme, depending on how the phone is rotated or how the screen is large. In this case you need to switch the button icon depending on the position within the split action bar: top vs. bottom.